# Importar grabaciones desde una base de datos

Tags: c#, sql

estoy extrayendo unas grabaciones almacenadas en una base de datos en SQl , para cambiarles el formato(sasf.) a WAV, pero el código en visual me muestra un error al extraer la info de la uri, alguien sabe cual puede ser el error ? Creo que puede estar en la parte de string[] segments = downloadUri , pero no estoy seguro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es el error concreto que obtienes?  Yo pruebo el código y no arroja errores.

Comment: Me sale que la Uri esta vacía o no se encontró

Comment: Podría molestarte tal vez con una video llamada y te muestro ?

Comment: Jamás he usado objetos Uri y he tenido que investigar un poco para ver de dónde venía el error. El código está bien parece, el problema lo tienes con las Uri. Si le pasas una Uri errónea o vacía pues no va a funcionar. Centra tus esfuerzos el obtener dichas uris de forma correcta.